# Como colocar um List<> em um ListView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lista, listview

Eu tenho um método para ler meu banco de dados que me retorna um List<>, gostaria de saber como eu faço para exibir esse List<> em um componente ListView

```
 DLL dll = new DLL();
 dll.listaVeiculoss(); //Esse método retorna um List<Veiculios>
 metroListView2; //Esse é um componente do tipo ListView
```

Comment: Você está usando winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supondo que você tem uma classe com as seguintes propriedades:

```
public class Veiculos
{
    public int idVeiculo { get; set; }
    public string Fabricante { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
}
```

Então faça isso:

```
//Adicionando alguns itens na lista:
List<Veiculos> listaVeiculos = new List<Veiculos> {
    new Veiculos { idVeiculo = 1, Fabricante = "Fiat", Modelo = "Palio" },
    new Veiculos { idVeiculo = 1, Fabricante = "Volkswagen", Modelo = "Fusca" },
    new Veiculos { idVeiculo = 1, Fabricante = "Ford", Modelo = "Fiesta" }
};
//Mudei a visualização para detalhes para cada item aparecer em coluna...
listView1.View = View.Details;
//Adicionei as colunas que irei mostrar na listView
listView1.Columns.Add("idVeiculo");
listView1.Columns.Add("Fabricante");
listView1.Columns.Add("Palio");

//Percorre a lista adicionando as linhas do ListView
foreach(var item in listaVeiculos)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { item.idVeiculo.ToString(), item.Fabricante, item.Modelo }));
}
```